# Django TemporaryUploadedFile different behaviour under Python2/3 with delete=False

Tags: python, django, temporary-files

Why does the `TemporaryUploadedFile` get deleted in Python 3 while in Python 2 it stays in `/tmp/` directory? And how would I keep the behavior of Python 2 while using 3?

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import TemporaryUploadedFile

with TemporaryUploadedFile('something.txt', 'text/plain', 0, 'UTF-8') as tmp_file:
    tmp_file_path = tmp_file.temporary_file_path()
    tmp_file.file.delete = False
    print(tmp_file_path)
```

Running this block of code under Python 2 keeps the file in `/tmp/` directory while on Python 3 it gets deleted.

```
[ray@fedora tmp]$ ls | grep tmp
tmpvSmI8b.upload       #generated in Python 2
```

```
PY2 version 2.7.18
PY3 version 3.7.12
Django 1.11.29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the details of why this behavior is different but if you want to keep file in `/tmp/` you need to instantiate `NamedTemporaryFile` with `delete=False` atrributes. Like this:

```
NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, ...)
```